# Is it possible to use symbol-macrolet to get labels-like behavior?

Tags: macros, common-lisp

In other words, is it possible to locally define a function in a way similar to how `flet` or `labels` does it? My final goal is to have a macro similar to `labels` which instead of regular functions uses instances of `funcallable-standard-class` and not having to use `funcall`. A use-case might look like the one below:

```
(funcallable-let ((foo func-class :initargs ...))
  (foo ...))
```

`symbol-macrolet` seems to only expand when not in the head position. If I try `(setf (symbol-function 'foo) (make-instance 'some-funcallable-class))` this sets it globally for this symbol an not for the scope of the enclosing `let`.

---

Here's what I could get so far (but it doesn't work because macrolet wouldn't expand in this scenario...)

```
(defclass func ()
  ((state :initarg :state :accessor state-of))
  (:metaclass sb-mop:funcallable-standard-class))

(defmethod initialize-instance :after ((this func) &rest initargs)
  (declare (ignore initargs))
  (sb-mop:set-funcallable-instance-function
   this (lambda ()
          (format t "~&I am: ~s, my state is: ~s" this (state-of this)))))

(defmacro funcallable-let (bindings &body body)
  (loop :for binding :in bindings
     :for name := (car binding)
     :for class := (cadr binding)
     :for init-args := (cddr binding)
     :collect `(,name (make-instance ',class ,.init-args)) :into classes
     :collect `(,name (&rest args) (list 'apply '',name args)) :into macrolets
     :collect name :into ignorables
     :finally
     (return
       `(let ,classes
          (declare (ignorable ,@ignorables))
          (macrolet ,macrolets
            ,@body)))))

(defun test-funcallable-let ()
  (funcallable-let ((f func :state :f-state)
                    (g func :state :g-state))
    (f) (funcall 'g)))
```

---

This is somewhat modified Lars' Brinkoff macro:

```
(defmacro funcallable-let (bindings &body body)
  (loop
     :for binding :in bindings
     :for symbol := (gensym)
     :for name := (car binding)
     :for class := (cadr binding)
     :for init-args := (cddr binding)
     :collect `(,symbol (make-instance ',class ,.init-args)) :into lets
     :collect `(,name (&rest args) (apply ',symbol args)) :into flets
     :collect symbol :into ignorables
     :finally
     (return
       `(let ,lets
          (declare (ignorable ,@ignorables))
          (flet ,flets ,@body)))))
```

Which wouldn't work either.

Comment: `symbol-macrolet` only expands when the symbol is used as a variable name. The head position is a function name, not a variable name, so it doesn't expand there. If you want it to expand in the function position, use `macrolet`.

Comment: @Barmar with `macrolet` there's the exact opposite problem - I wouldn't be able to use the symbol with `funcall` or `reduce` or what have you... (or at least I can't see how'd I do it).

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish that `flet` and `labels` don't provide. Maybe if you showed a use-case.

Comment: If `macrolet` works for one case, and `symbol-macrolet` works for the other, why not write a macro that expands into *both* so that you get something that works for both cases?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I hoped for there to be a cheaper way :)

Comment: What's not cheap about it? They're macros, so the transformation is done at compile time, not run time.  You'll be using just about the least amount of overhead as you can. :)  Especially since you can have, e.g., the symbol-macrolet expand `x` into `(x)`, where `x` will have been defined with `macrolet`.  It's not even all that much code to write.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor the thing is, I can't even get that to work...

Comment: @wvxvw If the function of the funcallable instance is set with `sb-mop:set-funcallable-instance-function`, what's the purpose of the lambda-list in `(funcallable-let ((foo (<lambda-list>) :initargs ...))
  (foo ...))`?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor please nevermind that, I haven't thought it well through when I wrote it. There's a better example below it (it doesn't have lambda-list). I'll edit that one in a moment.

Comment: OK, I've posted a version, too.  It seems like you want `(f x y z)` to expand to `(funcall f x y z)`, and that works, and you want `f`, when used _not_ in a head position, to evaluate to the funcallable object.  Are there any other requirements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, we want the value of `f` to be the funcallable object, so that things like `(setf (state-of f) new-state)` work, but also a macro definition for `f`, so that `(f 1 2 3)` expands to `(funcall f 1 2 3)`.  Let's write some direct code first.  First, your `func` definition, but with a slightly different funcallable instance function, so that we can pass some arguments in and see what they are:

```
(defclass func ()
  ((state :initarg :state :accessor state-of))
  (:metaclass sb-mop:funcallable-standard-class))

(defmethod initialize-instance :after ((this func) &rest initargs)
  (declare (ignore initargs))
  (sb-mop:set-funcallable-instance-function
   this (lambda (&rest args)
          (format t "~&I am: ~s, my state is: ~s, my args were ~s" this (state-of this) args))))
```

Then, we can write the code that we'd want the `funcallable-let` to expand into.  As the output shows, `f` in a head position ends up being a call to the funcallable instance, but `f` in a non head position is a variable that has the funcallable instance as a value, so you can, e.g., `(setf (state-of f) new-state)`:

```
(let ((f (make-instance 'func :state 34)))
  (macrolet ((f (&rest args)
               `(funcall f ,@args)))
    (f 1 2 3)
    (setf (state-of f) 89)
    (f 4 5 6)))

; I am: #<FUNC {1002A0B329}>, my state is: 34, my args were (1 2 3)
; I am: #<FUNC {1002A0B329}>, my state is: 89, my args were (4 5 6)
```

That seems good.  Now we just need to macroify it:

```
(defmacro funcallable-let (bindings &body body)
  `(let (,@(loop :for (name . initargs) :in bindings
             :collect `(,name (make-instance 'func ,@initargs))))
     (macrolet (,@(loop :for (name . initargs) :in bindings
                    :collect `(,name (&rest args)
                                     `(funcall ,',name ,@args))))
       ,@body)))
```

The macroexpansion looks right:

```
CL-USER> (pprint (macroexpand '(funcallable-let ((f :state 34))
                                (f 1 2 3))))

(LET ((F (MAKE-INSTANCE 'FUNC :STATE 34)))
  (MACROLET ((F (&REST ARGS)
               `(FUNCALL F ,@ARGS)))
    (F 1 2 3)))
```

And the behavior seems right (you can call with `(f ...)` or with `(funcall f ...)`, and you can `(setf (state-of f) ...)`:

```
CL-USER> (funcallable-let ((f :state 34))
           (f 1 2 3)
           (setf (state-of f) 89)
           (f 4 5 6)
           (setf (state-of f) 62)
           (funcall f 7 8 9))
I am: #<FUNC {1002BEC389}>, my state is: 34, my args were (1 2 3)
I am: #<FUNC {1002BEC389}>, my state is: 89, my args were (4 5 6)
I am: #<FUNC {1002BEC389}>, my state is: 62, my args were (7 8 9)
NIL
```

Comment: OK, this worked, except that inside the body `(funcall 'f ...)` doesn't expand as expected, but `(funcall f ...)` does (the left-over from `let`). My variant generates very similar code, expect where you have ``\`(funcall ,',name ,@args)`` I have `(list 'apply ',name 'args)` I thought these should be identical...

Comment: @wvxvw The macro expansion code isn't so important, as long as the code that it generates is the same.  You won't be able to make `(funcall 'f ...)` work.  `funcall` takes a [_function designator_](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_f.htm#function_designator) which, if it's a symbol, denotes "the function named by that symbol in the global environment". (i) You're working with a funcallable, not a function. (ii) You're not working in the global environment.  Even `(flet ((f ...)) (funcall 'f ...)` calls the global, not the local.

Comment: Ahhh... ok, now I see, I thought that I could `funcall` a symbol which is the name defined in `labels`, but I actually have to pass it a function reference, not a symbol. OK, thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but maybe this?

```lisp
(defmacro funcallable-let (bindings &body body)
  (let ((gensyms (loop repeat (length bindings) collect (gensym))))
    `(let ,(loop for (name value) in bindings and g in gensyms
                 collect `(,g ,value))
       (flet ,(loop for (name value) in bindings and g in gensyms
                    collect `(,name (&rest args) (apply ,g args)))
         ,@body))))
```

Sample usage:

```
(funcallable-let ((foo (make-instance 'some-funcallable-class :initargs ...)))
  (foo ...))
```

Comment: Nope, this won't do because it creates a bunch of wrapper functions around the funcallable objects, which defies the purpose of using funcallable objects (you won't be able to specialize methods on them / perform other useful things like changing slot values etc.)

Comment: @wvxvw I'm now reading the other answers a bit more closely, and [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19934977/1281433) is similar to this, except that I've used a `macrolet` instead of `flet`.

Answer (score 1):

For a similar problem see `GENERIC-FLET` and `GENERIC-LABELS` of CLtL2 and why it was removed in ANSI Common Lisp.

http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Issues/iss181_w.htm

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting, I didn't know these macros ever existed. However in what I'm trying to do the class definition is outside the macro, so I can reuse the code that handles functions of the extended type in a uniform way across multiple functions. Technically, nothing stops me from doing it even now, the only thing that bothers me is the overly verbose syntax (i.e. I've to write `(funcall 'foo ...)` instead of just `(foo ...)`.